# Regular Expression for forward slash

Tags: javascript

Can someone provide a regular expression in Javascript which allows everything except a forward slash(/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (I'm assuming you want to remove all forward slashes "/"):

```
var string = "/ I'm going to remove everything but this / cool / !@#!@123 `23";
string = string.replace(/\//g, '');
console.log(string); // I'm going to remove everything but this  cool  !@#!@123 `23
```

The regular expression is 
`/\//g`

- We have to escape the forward slash with a backslash (\)
- The "g" is for global to look for all matches

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have to use regular expression to validate the input entered by the user. The user input should not contain slash, if it exists then raise an alert(dont have to remove slash from the input).
So basically I need a regular expression that allows alphabets/digits and all special characters apart from slash. So regular expression should contain a format that allows these things apart from slash

Comment: Gotcha! In this case you can use the test method. The regex would still be the same:

`/\//.test("/ I'm going to remove everything but this / cool / !@#!@123 23")`

This would return `true` for any string that contains a backslash.